# Como y cuando se usaría la tabla tipos_de_documento con cardinalidad a una tabla clientes

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos, innodb

Soy estudiante de ingeniería de sistemas,

tengo una tabla llamada **clientes** con los campos **identificación**, **tipo_identificación**, **nombre** y **apellido**, y otra tabla llamada **tipos_de_documento** con los campos **id_tipo_documento** y **nombre_tipo_documento**.

mi profesor me comento que se crea la tabla **tipos_de_documento** para mantener la integridad de la **base de datos**,

pero mi duda surge al momento de usarlo con html y php, con la segunda tabla **tipos_de_documento** debería crear un ciclo **while** con **php** para que cree un **combobox** que se rellena con los tipos de documentos registrados en esa tabla o es una manera errónea de hacerlo? ademas no sabría que poner en el **value** del **option** si el **id_tipo_documento** o el **nombre_tipo_documento**

**Editado:**

Esto es lo que hago para mostrarlos en el formulario de registro:

```
<select name="tipo_identificacion" required>
<?php
// Aqui llamo los valores de la tabla tipos_de_identificacion de la base de datos
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tipos_de_identificacion";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "<option value='".$row["id_tipo_identificacion"]."'>".$row["nombre_tipo_identificacion"]."</option>";
echo "<br>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Y esto es lo que hago para mostrar los datos en pantalla:

lo que hago es llamar los datos de la tabla clientes y mostrarlos tal cual como me los regresa la consulta, al haber registrado el cliente en el campo tipo_identificacion colocando el id_tipo_identificacion y no el campo tipo_identificacion, me va a mostrar en la tabla Tipo Identificacion -> 1 y no Tipo Identificacion -> CC

por ejemplo el html:

```css
table, tr, th, td{
  border: 1px solid #111;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <th>Identificacion</th>
   <th>Tipo Identificacion</th>
   <th>Nombre</th>
   <th>Apellido</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>123456789</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>Juan</td>
   <td>Perez</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Deberia quedar asi:

```css
table, tr, th, td{
  border: 1px solid #111;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <th>Identificacion</th>
   <th>Tipo Identificacion</th>
   <th>Nombre</th>
   <th>Apellido</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>123456789</td>
   <td>CC</td>
   <td>Juan</td>
   <td>Perez</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

**Tabla: Clientes**
[image: Tabla Clientes]
**Tabla: Tipos de Identificacion**
[image: Tabla Tipos de Identificacion]
No se si sea correcto dejar la tabla **tipos_identificacion** sin un campo **id** o uno por el estilo

Answer (score 0):

Tabla de `clientes` debe de llevar principalmente un `ididentificacion` debe ser `INT` tu lo tienes `VARCHAR` debido a que se deben hacer las realaciones de la siguiente forma: En tu tabla `identificaciones` debe ir de la siguiente forma: `id` en `INT` y `nombre` en `VARCHAR` tu solo tienes un campo `VARCHAR` para el nombre.

una ves que las tablas se encuentre tal cual te dije, continuamos con adjuntar la informacion de tu tabla `identificacion` a tu tabla `clientes`. entonces la consulta seria utilizar INNER JOIN para poder hacer referencia a otra tabla de manera que tu codigo debe ir de la siguiente forma:

```
<select name="tipo_identificacion" required>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes INNER JOIN identificaciones.nombre as nombre_identificacion WHERE clientes.ididentificacion = identificaciones.id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "<option value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["nombre_identificacion"]."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

con eso estamos uniendo las dos tablas en una sola, simplemente le estamos pasando el nombre de las identificaciones segun corresponda el `ididentificacion` en tu tabla `clientes`

Te dejo un ejemplo de como usar `JOINS` [SQL INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: Manuel Morales muchas gracias por responder, al leer tu pregunta me surge otra duda, entonces cuando yo desee mostrar esos datos en pantalla, como puedo hacer para que al llamar los valores de la tabla clientes, en el campo tipo_identificación no aparezca "1" sino el nombre_del_tipo_identificación, me explico?

Comment: Eso depende, te recomiendo que vallas plasmando lo que vallas realizando y nosotros te corregimos o te damos soluciones. Inserta tus codigos que has echo para mostrar la informacion

Comment: Ya agregue un poco de código, espero me entiendas y puedas colaborarme, Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: agrega tambien una imagen de las dos tablas que estas usando para ayudarte hacerlo

Comment: Ya agregue las imágenes, pero viendo las dos tablas no se si sea correcto dejar la tabla **tipos_identificacion** sin un campo **id** o uno por el estilo, Gracias nuevamente por tu ayuda.

Comment: he actualizado mi respuesta, verifica